# Why value of my attribute doesn't change?

Tags: javascript, attributes, fill

I've wanted to add something like new tab button but I don't know how to change color of it in JS code. My element:

```
<svg width="10rem" height="10rem" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-plus- 
    square" fill="gray" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                       <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14 1H2a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v12a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 
     1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1zM2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 
   0- 
    2-2H2z"/>
                       <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h- 
     3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z"/>
                   </svg>
```

My JS:

```
    $('svg').on('mouseenter', 'svg', function() {
        this.fill = 'black';
    }).on('mouseleave', 'svg', function() {
        this.fill = 'gray';
    })
```

Comment: I doesn't look like you have a nested <svg> tag in your <svg> tag.  That's what `$('svg').on('mouseevent', **'svg'**` is matching against

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to alter the style of the SVG, not the property itself. Your event listener was also looking for a nested element.

```js
$('svg').on('mouseenter', function() {
  this.style.fill = 'black';
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  this.style.fill = 'gray';
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="10rem" height="10rem" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-plus- 
    square" fill="gray" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14 1H2a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v12a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 
     1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1zM2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 
   0- 
    2-2H2z"/>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h- 
     3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z"/>
</svg>
```